# linker error in Android NDK r25c when cross-compiling FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I am cross compiling FFmpeg for Android(aarch64) using Android NDK r25c on Linux x86_64 platform. The errors generated by the linker are because of enabling the `LTO` option.
On disabling the LTO options(`--enable-lto` optional config and `-flto=thin` cc-flag), there are no failures.

FFmpeg config:

```bash
./configure --arch=aarch64 --target-os=android --enable-cross-compile --disable-everything \ 
 --disable-network --disable-autodetect --enable-small --disable-debug --disable-doc \ 
 --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-htmlpages --disable-shared \
 --enable-static --enable-decoder='aac*,ac3*,opus,vorbis,mjpeg,mp3' \ 
 --enable-demuxer='mov,m4v,matroska,image2,mp3' --enable-protocol=file --enable-muxer='mp3,mp4,webm,null' \  
 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-encoder=libmp3lame --enable-filter=aresample --enable-logging \ 
 --enable-pthreads --enable-parser='vorbis,opus,vp8,vp9,mjpeg,h264,aac*,ac3*,mpegvideo,mpegaudio,mpeg4video' \
 --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffplay --prefix='$HOME/Downloads/custom_build' --enable-lto \
 --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/Downloads/custom_build/include -I$HOME/Downloads/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/include -O3 -flto=thin" \
 --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/Downloads/custom_build/lib -L$HOME/Downloads/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64" \
 --cc="aarch64-linux-android33-clang" --nm=llvm-nm --strip=llvm-strip
```

Error:

```bash
ld: error: undefined symbol: av_packet_alloc
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced 10 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_usleep
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(main)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(retry_transfer_wrapper)

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_log
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced 745 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_thread_message_queue_send
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced 1 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_thread_message_queue_recv
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(main)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ffmpeg_cleanup)

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_rescale_q
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced 62 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_packet_move_ref
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(submit_packet)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(pkt_move)
>>> referenced 3 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_thread_message_queue_set_err_recv
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_packet_free
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(input_thread)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(mux_check_init)
>>> referenced 13 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_compare_ts
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_duration_update)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(finish_stream)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(finish_stream)
>>> referenced 10 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_dict_set_int
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(of_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(mov_read_ftyp)
>>> referenced 1 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_dict_get
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(configure_filtergraph)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(main)
>>> referenced 25 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_opt_set_dict
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(init_output_stream_wrapper)
>>> referenced 4 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_strdup
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced 29 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_mallocz
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(graph_parse)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(graph_parse)
>>> referenced 62 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_opt_set_defaults
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(avfilter_graph_alloc)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(avfilter_graph_alloc_filter)
>>> referenced 5 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_fast_malloc
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_free
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced 62 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_freep
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced 205 more times

ld: error: undefined symbol: av_asprintf
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(ifile_open)
>>> referenced by ld-temp.o
>>>               lto.tmp:(describe_filter_link)
>>> referenced 3 more times

ld: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now (use -error-limit=0 to see all errors)
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makefile:131: ffmpeg_g] Error 1
```

I also compiled `LAME` encoder (version 3.100) with LTO options, and it worked just fine.
How to resolve the error?

**The **libLTO.so** file is present under `lib64/` hence added that to the --extra-ldflags optional config.
****PATH** env contains `$HOME/Downloads/android-ndk-r25c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin`